# Convert xml string to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, xcode

```
NSString *xml=@"<string>aaaa</string><string>bbbb</string><string>ccccc</string>";
```

I Want to store text of every elemnt in NSMutableArray

Comment: have you tried anything.. there are allot of tutorial here.. just parse it and you will get you result..

Comment: please see my answer and follow the same link..

Answer (score 1):

Either you use xml parser which is the best option.
I suggest you [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) and [its performance is better than others](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project)

or

Try this. `mtbArray` is you all require

```
NSString *xml=@"<string>aaaa</string><string>bbbb</string><string>ccccc</string>";
xml = [xml stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"</string>" withString:@""];
NSArray *array = [xml componentsSeparatedByString:@"<string>"];
NSMutableArray *mtbArray = [array mutableCopy];
if ([mtbArray count]) {
    [mtbArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: I would suggest the XML parser rather than transforming the xml string. But either way will work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can better use the [NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the purpose. Hope this helps you.